# Java Generics: Infer and reference a type used in the class instantiation

Tags: java, generics

Given a KeyHolder interface such as the following:

```
public interface KeyHolder<K extends Key> {
    K getKey();
}
```

I'd like to create a class like this:

```
public KeyHolderSet<H extends KeyHolder<K extends Key>> extends HashSet<H> {
   public Set<K> getKeySet() {
       Set<K> keySet = new HashSet<K>();
       for (H keyHolder : this) {
           keySet.add(keyHolder.getKey());
       }
       return keySet;
   }
}
```

But that doesn't work, the closest I can get is this:

```
public KeyHolderSet<H extends KeyHolder<? extends Key>> extends HashSet<H> {
   public <K extends Key> Set<K> getKeySet() {
       Set<K> keySet = new HashSet<K>();
       for (H keyHolder : this) {
           // Explicit cast to K
           keySet.add((K)keyHolder.getKey());
       }
       return keySet;
   }
}
```

Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write it like this:

```
public KeyHolderSet<K extends Key, H extends KeyHolder<K>> extends HashSet<H> {
    public Set<K> getKeySet() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you will have to declare the type of K first and it cannot be inferred.

Comment: Aargh, yes, I should have added that as another option, but it is blindingly painful to have to declare the Key separately :(

Comment: The other option is to use bounded wildcards (`? extends...`) but you will end up adding suppressing warnings for unchecked conversion all over the place...

Comment: Hi Finbarr, could you please provide an example of what you mean by using bounded wildcards? Does it differ from my second solution?

Comment: I see you have edited your question slightly. Your second solution is exactly what I was talking about when I mentioned bounded wildcards. This solution is cleaner whenever you want to make use of the class, but the class itself is polluted with warnings/`SuppressWarning` annotations.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the implementation class of the KeyHolder that is stored in the set is not important, you could try something like this:

```
public class KeyHolderSet<K extends Key> extends HashSet<KeyHolder<K>> {
    public Set<K> getKeySet() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Unfortunately in my case the implementation of KeyHolder is important, but hopefully this solution will work for others.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
public class KeyHolderSet<K extends Key, H extends KeyHolder<K>> extends
        HashSet<H> {
    public Set<K> getKeySet() {
        ...
    }
}
```

if you don't mind parameterizing KeyHolderSet twice.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `KeyHolder<K extends Key>` it seems unnecessary to use `KeyHolderSet<H extends KeyHolder<K extends Key>>` Just stick with:

```
public class KeyHolderSet<H extends KeyHolder<?>>
```

and you should be ok.

Edit: I see your problem with `getKeySet()`. This method should return H instead of K. H will be typed with what you entered in the declaration of KeyHolderSet (The variabe, not the class).

```
public class KeyHolderSet<H extends KeyHolder<?>> extends HashSet<H> {

  private H theKeySet;

  public void setKeySet(H keyset) {
    theKeySet = keyset;
  }

  public H getKeySet() {
    return theKeySet;
  }
}
```

-

```
class betterKey extends Key {
}
```

-

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyHolder<betterKey> kh = new KeyHolder<betterKey>() {
    };
    KeyHolderSet<KeyHolder<betterKey>> khs = new KeyHolderSet<KeyHolder<betterKey>>();
    khs.setKeySet(kh);

    KeyHolder<Key> kh2 = khs.getKeySet(); // Type mismatch
  }
```

As you can see `khs.getKeySet()` returns `KeyHolder<betterKey>` as expected.

Edit2:
You can build up the set outside the KeyHolderSet class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyHolderSet<KeyHolder<betterKey>> khs = new KeyHolderSet<KeyHolder<betterKey>>();
    Set<betterKey> bks = new HashSet<betterKey>();
    for (KeyHolder<betterKey> kh : khs) {
      bks.add(kh.getKey());
    }
  }
```

One alternate solution i came up with is returning a completely generic Set, remember all type checking will be lost this way.

```
public class KeyHolderSet<H extends KeyHolder<?>> extends HashSet<H> {
  public <K extends Key> Set<K> getKeySet() {
    Set<K> s = new HashSet<K>();
    for (H keyHolder : this) {
      s.add((K) keyHolder.getKey()); // Unchecked cast
    }
    return s;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyHolderSet<KeyHolder<betterKey>> khs = new KeyHolderSet<KeyHolder<betterKey>>();
    Set<Key> ks = khs.getKeySet(); // No problem
    Set<betterKey> bks = khs.getKeySet(); // No problem
    Set<evenBetterKey> ss = khs.getKeySet(); // No problem
  }
}

class betterKey implements Key {
}

class evenBetterKey extends betterKey {
}
```

Comment: Hi Dorus. Perhaps the intention wasn't clear. I don't expect getKeySet to return a KeyHolder, I expect it to return a Set<Key>. I've updated the question to give a clear indication of the expected behaviour.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is returning a Set<KeyHolder>, and then call getKey on the items in the set. Possible while building a Set<Key>. I update my answer, but i doubt this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I realized returning a `Set<KeyHolder>` has no use, this is exactly what the `KeyHolderSet<KeyHolder<betterKey>>` is by itself. You can just iterate over that and retrieve the Keys. However I can't put it in a function that returns the right type.

Comment: Oops, my last solution is exactly what you put in the "closest I can get" part. You are stuck with either that, or give your class 2 generics like described in the other answers.